# isInBitmapMemoryCache return true for different url

Tags: android, fresco

I have an image with different size:

http://aaa/16ad9522e15dc9c3fdfa5c4b.jpeg!custom500.jpg

and

http://aaa/16ad9522e15dc9c3fdfa5c4b.jpeg!

When I use fresco to load these images, I use isInBitmapMemoryCache to check if it is in bitmap memory. The first one is ok, but I found it return true for the second one and the result of imageDataSource is null. So what is the right way to load different images?

Thanks a lot.

```
if (imagePipeline.isInBitmapMemoryCache(uri)) {
    getImageBitmapFromMemory(uri, imagePipeline)
} else {
    getImageBitmapFromNet(uri, imagePipeline)
}

if (imagePipeline.isInBitmapMemoryCache(uri)) {
    val imageDataSource = imagePipeline.fetchImageFromBitmapCache(imageRequest, null)
    val imageReference = imageDataSource.result
    if (imageReference != null) { ... }
```

Comment: most of the image library store cash if the most of the part is equal in url , That is why happen this there for clear the cash before load the image

Comment: @Dulanga But if I always clear cache before load, what is the meaning of cache? I tried to use custom cache key factory, but isInBitmapMemoryCache still return true. For now I have to get cache key and compare by myself, and I do not know whether there is a better way.